# Get the largest value (number) of an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to earn the highest value of the `scores` object.

I have a global object "implementations":

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "project": 'name project',
    "scores": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "user_id": 30,
        "implementation_id": 5,
        "score": "12.00",
        "comment": "C'est de la merde, ça vient d’Anthony."
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "user_id": 31,
        "implementation_id": 5,
        "score": "15.00",
        "comment": "Super"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "project": 'name project',
    "scores": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "user_id": 30,
        "implementation_id": 6,
        "score": "20.00",
        "comment": "Super!"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "user_id": 31,
        "implementation_id": 6,
        "score": "12.00",
        "comment": "Super"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "user_id": 36,
        "implementation_id": 6,
        "score": "10.00",
        "comment": "Super"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For example, in the above object, there are 2 scores in object 1, and 3 scores in object 2.

I would like the greatest value of both. If we add a third object, and there are 5 scores, I would like to get 5.

How to do that with a javascript function?

Thank you

Comment: please show the expected results you want from the sample `implementations` object you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest approach is create a dummy value and calculate the count. Then sort it.

```
const scoresList = [
  {
    "id": 5,
    "project": 'name project',
    "scores": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "user_id": 30,
        "implementation_id": 5,
        "score": "12.00",
        "comment": "C'est de la merde, ça vient d’Anthony."
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "user_id": 31,
        "implementation_id": 5,
        "score": "15.00",
        "comment": "Super"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "project": 'name project',
    "scores": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "user_id": 30,
        "implementation_id": 6,
        "score": "20.00",
        "comment": "Super!"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "user_id": 31,
        "implementation_id": 6,
        "score": "12.00",
        "comment": "Super"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "user_id": 36,
        "implementation_id": 6,
        "score": "10.00",
        "comment": "Super"
      }
    ]
  }
];

for(var i = 0; i < scoresList.length; i++){
   //create a dummy variable scoreCount
    scoresList[i].scoreCount = 0;
    if(scoresList[i].scores){
              scoresList[i].scoreCount = scoresList[i].scores.length;
    }

}
scoresList.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return b.scoreCount - a.scoreCount
});

console.log(scoresList[0]); //This will give you the score with highest count
```

Answer (score 0):

In person, I think that these kind of tasks can be handled by **pure JS**

Assuming `scores` holds the JSON data:

```
const groups = scores.map(item => item.scores)

const lengths = groups.map(set => set.length)

const max = Math.max(...lengths)
```

Pretty elegant (in my opinion at least)

**Side Note:**

A "flat" object containing the results would be retrieved by using:

```
const flatResults = Array.prototype.concat.apply([],scores.map(item => item.scores)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the scores to an array of arrays of of numbers:`data.map(item=>item.scores.map(x=>x.score).map(Number))`

Then map again with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the highest of each nested array:`.map(scores=>scores.reduce((result,score)=>Math.max(result,score),0))`. That will get the highest score per data item.

If you would rather have the highest score over all you can [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and reduce:`.flat().reduce((result,score)=>Math.max(result,score),0)`

```js
const data = [{"id":5,"project":"name project","scores":[{"id":7,"user_id":30,"implementation_id":5,"score":"12.00","comment":"C'est de la merde, ça vient d’Anthony."},{"id":10,"user_id":31,"implementation_id":5,"score":"15.00","comment":"Super"}]},{"id":6,"project":"name project","scores":[{"id":8,"user_id":30,"implementation_id":6,"score":"20.00","comment":"Super!"},{"id":11,"user_id":31,"implementation_id":6,"score":"12.00","comment":"Super"},{"id":15,"user_id":36,"implementation_id":6,"score":"10.00","comment":"Super"}]}];


console.log(
  'highest per data item:',
  data.map(item=>item.scores.map(x=>x.score).map(Number))
    .map(scores=>scores.reduce((result,score)=>Math.max(result,score),0))
);

console.log(
  'highest over all:',
  data.map(item=>item.scores.map(x=>x.score).map(Number))
    .flat().reduce((result,score)=>Math.max(result,score),0)
);
```